# Porting an application to python 3

Tags: python-3.x

I have an application using  dependencies like Python Imaging Library(PIL), PyQt, python-dbus.
I want to port this application to python 3. From internet i found that these packages have not been ported to python 3. Do we have an alternative for these packages.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I have found from these libraries for Python 3.

Python Image Library: https://github.com/gpolo/pil-py3k

PyQt download: http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/software/pyqt/download

I could not find anything for Python-dbus, but there is an interesting thread discussing it here:
http://old.nabble.com/PyQt-and-DBus-in-Python-3-td32769073.html.